# How to hide password from jenkins shell output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

I have two scripts first on file system,second into jenkins job.
Second script calling the first and passed parameters into it.
Parameters contains password parameter. 
How can I hide password into logs?
I have tried to hide output by using exec command but problem wasn't solved.

Comment: instead of plain text you can use `echo "passwd string" | base64` and `base64 --decode`

Comment: I can use base64 but it's not a good idea. Script will become unusable without jenkins becouse passwords without encoding passed by user always will be incorrect, and user will must know unnecessary info.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Mask Passwords plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) does just that.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution was helpful.

Comment: The Mask Passwords plugin only allows for preset passwords to be passed in to the build process, so it really does nothing for the security of the Job. I need a password parameter that needs to be entered every time the job is run (as a parameter) and I need that to be masked in the console output. From what I am reading, going to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System and selecting to mask Password Parameters should work, but it is not for some reason.. any suggestions?

Comment: @IanTait Comments are not the right place for this - please post another question for this issue.

Comment: you need know, even with this plugin, if you are the jenkins admin, you can un-mask it and see the password in logs.

Comment: @BMW There's no way you are going to be able to hide the password from the actual server admin.

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2019-08-07/#SECURITY-157

Answer (score 1):

Please find below my findings with solution [without using Mask Passwords plugin]:

**Brief Description about my jenkins job:**
I wrote a job which downloads the artifacts from Nexus based on the parameters given at run-time and then makes a Database SQL connection and deploy the SQL scripts using maven flyway plugin. My job takes - Environment, Database Schema, Artifact version number, Flyway command, Database User and it's password as input parameters.

**Brief Background about problem:**
While passing the PASSWORD as MAVEN GOAL (Parameter), it was coming in Jenkins Console as a plain text.
Although I was using "Password Parameter" to pass the password at run-time but then also it was coming as plain text in console.

I tried to use the "secret text" to encrypt the password but then my job started failing because the encrypted password was getting passed to Maven Goals, which was not able to connect to DB.

**Solution:**

I used ***"Inject passwords to the build as environment variables"*** from Build Environment and defined its value as my "password parameter" (my password parameter name was db_password) which I am passing as parameter at run-time (eg.: I defined my inject password value as : ${db_password}  ).

And this is working as expected. The password which I am passing while running my job is coming as [*******]

> [console log:
>   Executing Maven:  -B -f /work/jenkins_data/workspace/S2/database-deployment-via-flyway-EDOS/pom.xml clean compile -Ddb=UAT_cms_core -DdatabaseSchema=cms-core -Dmode=info -DdeploymentVersion=1.2.9 -Ddb_user=DB_USER -Ddb_password=[*******]
>   ]