# How to hide passwords in Jenkins console output?

Tags: shell, jenkins, console, passwords

The Mask Passwords plugin only allows for preset passwords to be passed in to the build process, so it really does nothing for the security of the Job.

I need a password parameter that needs to be entered every time the job is run (as a parameter) and I need that to be masked in the console output.

From what I am reading, going to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System and selecting to mask Password Parameters should work, but it is not for some reason.. any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide password from jenkins shell output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606922/how-to-hide-password-from-jenkins-shell-output)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tested with Jenkins 1.609.1 and [Mask Passwords Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) 2.7.3. You need to activate it in the "Configure System" and also in the job you want to use this. In the job configuration is a point "Mask passwords" which must be activated and then will use the global config to mask passwords.

Comment: you need know, even with this plugin, if you are the jenkins admin, you can un-mask it and see the password in logs.

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2019-08-07/#SECURITY-157

Comment: This seems to be fixed with version 2.13 of the plugin. See https://plugins.jenkins.io/mask-passwords/#releases Released 03.04.2020.

Comment: seems the jenkins doesn't update it with https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisories/. I can still see the warning on my jenkins server: "Warnings have been published for the following currently installed components:
Mask Passwords Plugin 2.13
Plain text passwords shown in global configuration form fields"

Answer (score 15):

in case that you have a Linux builder you can hide the output of the shell command
under the execute shell in the command text box just add in the first line the line:

```
#!/bin/bash +x
some other commands...
```

this will hide only the output of the command with the password in the console output

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: But this doesn't hide Cloudfoundry apps password on Jenkins console.

Answer (score 10):

You can use credentials. Add secret text credentials and give and id that you'll use like the following:

```
          withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'DOCKER_USER', variable: 'DOCKER_USER'), string(credentialsId: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD', variable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD')]) {
            sh "docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD"
            sh "docker push '$DOCKER_USER/appName:test'" 
          }
```

`DOCKER_USER` AND `DOCKER_PASSWORD` are in the jenkins credentials store and will be replaced by `***` in the logs

Comment: If you return a string from the withCredentials block, the password can still get logged elsewhere when it's used, though... I need it filtered outside the withCredentials block, not just inside it.

Answer (score 4):

I am using here "Inject passwords to the build as environment variables" form "Build Environment". It's really works great. it will hide passwords form console.
Even more it also hide user input passwords through "password parameter"

Really cool !! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please find below my findings with solution [without using Mask Passwords plugin]:

**Brief Description about my jenkins job:**
I wrote a job which downloads the artifacts from Nexus based on the parameters given at run-time and then makes a Database SQL connection and deploy the SQL scripts using maven flyway plugin. My job takes - Environment, Database Schema, Artifact version number, Flyway command, Database User and it's password as input parameters.

**Brief Background about problem:**
While passing the PASSWORD as MAVEN GOAL (Parameter), it was coming in Jenkins Console as a plain text.
Although I was using "Password Parameter" to pass the password at run-time but then also it was coming as plain text in console.

I tried to use the "secret text" to encrypt the password but then my job started failing because the encrypted password was getting passed to Maven Goals, which was not able to connect to DB.

**Solution:**

I used ***"Inject passwords to the build as environment variables"*** from Build Environment and defined its value as my "password parameter" (my password parameter name was db_password) which I am passing as parameter at run-time (eg.: I defined my inject password value as : ${db_password}  ).

And this is working as expected. The password which I am passing while running my job is coming as [*******]

> [console log:
>   Executing Maven:  -B -f /work/jenkins_data/workspace/S2/database-deployment-via-flyway-EDOS/pom.xml clean compile -Ddb=UAT_cms_core -DdatabaseSchema=cms-core -Dmode=info -DdeploymentVersion=1.2.9 -Ddb_user=DB_USER -Ddb_password=[*******]
>   ]

Answer (score 1):

```
        stage('Database and user') {
      steps {
      sshagent(["${SSH_AGENT_ID}"]) {
        wrap([$class: "MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper", varPasswordPairs: [[password: RDS_USER_PASSWORD]]]) {
         withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'JENKINS_SMTP_CREDENTIALS', passwordVariable: 'SMTP_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'SMTP_USER')]) {
          ansiblePlaybook become: false, colorized: true, disableHostKeyChecking: true, extras: '-e BUILD_URL=${BUILD_URL} -e SMTP_SERVER=${SMTP_SERVER} -e SMTP_USER=${SMTP_USER} -e SMTP_PASSWORD=${SMTP_PASSWORD} -e BUILD_USER_EMAIL=${BUILD_USER_EMAIL} -e RDS_USER_PASSWORD=${RDS_USER_PASSWORD} -e BUILD_USER_ID=${BUILD_USER_ID} -e DIR=${WORKSPACE} -e GITLAB_TOKEN=${GITLAB_TOKEN} -e APP_NAME=${APP_NAME} -e AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION} -e PROJECT=${PROJECT} -e JENKINS_ACCOUNT=${JENKINS_ACCOUNT} -e GC_KEY=${GC_KEY} -e PS_ACTION=${PS_ACTION}  -e role=mysql', playbook: 'ansible/local.yml'
      }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Just add wrap([$class: "MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper", varPasswordPairs: [[password: RDS_USER_PASSWORD]]]) {}
where RDS_USER_PASSWORD - password which you need mask

Answer (score 0):

you can use Mask Passwords Plugin this is very use
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin