# Hide output inside Jenkins pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm propagating env variables thru Jenkins pipeline, this env's is parameterized like multi-line String parameters.
I handle this set of params thru `${PARMS}` to pipeline body.
I need to hide or mask part of this parameters from output and logs.
I need propagate this behavior only for specific Jenkins pipeline jobs.
How I can do it ?

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078376/how-to-hide-passwords-in-jenkins-console-output

Comment: Thank you, but this is not works for me because I'm using "multi-line String parameters"