# Jenkins parameter value not resolving for a bat command

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to resolve a parameter inside a windows path, so can we do that.

```
def Job_Name=params.Job_Name

pipeline {
    agent none
    options { 
        skipDefaultCheckout() 
    }
    stages {
    
    stage("Export_Package"){
            agent {
                label 'xxxxx'
            }
            steps{
                bat 'E:\\sashome\\SASPlatformObjectFramework\\9.4\\ExportPackage -user "xxxxx" -password "xxxxxx" -host "xxxxxxx.com" -port "1234" -package "E:\\sasconfig\\Lev1\\SASApp\\SASEnvironment\\SASCode\\Jobs\\Devops_EportJobs\\"${Job_Name}".spk" -objects "/Shared Data/Jenkins" -subprop "${Job_Name}".subprop'

            }
            
        }
       
    }
}
```

Can we call "${Job_Name}" like this inside the path?? If not, can someone please let me know how to accomplish the same. I just want to pass the Job_Name inside the path, so that I don't have to hard code the job_Name.spk and can keep it dynamic. Whatever Job_name I will pass on the Parameter it should pick that and resolve the same before .spk

Please help me if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read groovy string basics:
https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html

Basically, you're wrapping your argument with single quotes when you should be using double quotes. Then when using double quotes, escape all the double quotes within the argument itself:

```
bat "E:\\sashome\\SASPlatformObjectFramework\\9.4\\ExportPackage -user \"xxxxx\" -password \"xxxxxx\" -host \"xxxxxxx.com\" -port \"1234\" -package \"E:\\sasconfig\\Lev1\\SASApp\\SASEnvironment\\SASCode\\Jobs\\Devops_EportJobs\\\"${Job_Name}\".spk\" -objects \"/Shared Data/Jenkins\" -subprop \"${Job_Name}\".subprop"
```

From reading the comment, it seems this is what you are looking for (removed literal quotes around Job_Name variable):

```
bat "E:\\sashome\\SASPlatformObjectFramework\\9.4\\ExportPackage -user \"xxxxx\" -password \"xxxxxx\" -host \"xxxxxxx.com\" -port \"1234\" -package \"E:\\sasconfig\\Lev1\\SASApp\\SASEnvironment\\SASCode\\Jobs\\Devops_EportJobs\\${Job_Name}.spk\" -objects \"/Shared Data/Jenkins\" -subprop ${Job_Name}.subprop"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Perplexabot for your quick response, but the above line is giving " " around the resolved text. Like "E:\sasconfig\Lev1\SASApp\SASEnvironment\SASCode\Jobs\Devops_EportJobs\"Test_jenkings".spk" it's resolving. I believe I don't need the double quotes aound the Test_Jenkings name. Please guide.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you should be able to get rid of all the double quotes inside.

Comment: Then remove the quotes from around "${Job_Name}"!

Comment: Hopefully you removed the '"' along with the escape "\" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it's working perfectly. You are very much helpful and big round of applause for your quick responses.

Comment: Log:
Masking supported pattern matches of %USERNAME% or %PASSWORD%
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat

C:\Jenkins\workspace\pipeline-development\sas-batch-export-pkg-DEV>Echo **** 
****
[Pipeline] bat

C:\Jenkins\workspace\pipeline-development\sas-batch-export-pkg-DEV>Echo wkmd91R% 
wkmd91R%

Comment: Hi @Rajdeep , I am familiar with masking passwords using jenkins `sh` command but not `bat`. Perhaps this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078376/how-to-hide-passwords-in-jenkins-console-output

Comment: Hi  Perplexabot. I just  have a small query. Please help me to resolve it. I am trying replace some text inside a file with powershell command. The command is working totally fine, but I am not able to add the same command in Jenkins pipeline script. I tried from all possible ways, but somehow the command double quotes are not escaping in Jenkins. Below is the command you can see there's a double quote before "(Get-Content that's not escaping in pipeline script. With enclosed " " only powershell command is working.

Comment: powershell -Command "(Get-Content I:\users\desktop\stp\Jenkins_Test2_SASENTCSMGMT.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace [RegEx]::Escape('E:\config'), 'I:\config' } | Set-Content I:\users\desktop\stp\Jenkins_Test2_SASENTCSMGMT.txt"

Comment: so if I begin the command with bat "Complete command with double quotes" or sh "Complete command with double quotes" then how to take the complete command with double quotes before Get-Content and after SASENTCSMGMT.txt in Jenkins pipeline script. Hope you got my point..

Comment: .Hey Prep, please suggest something..I am waiting for your reply...