# How can we Encrypt Credentials in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, github, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline

I am using with Credential in Jenkins pipeline to use the masked credential globally

```
node(){

    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '6827ae64-c211-4bb9-b4cd-64eeca90be6f', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')])
```

but if I am using

```
def username

def password

node(){

        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '6827ae64-c211-4bb9-b4cd-64eeca90be6f', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
             username = USERNAME
            password  = PASSWORD

                }
```

I am able to see the Credential in console output. What is the way which we can encrypt this thing and make it secure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide password from jenkins shell output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606922/how-to-hide-password-from-jenkins-shell-output)

Comment: Answer is there ^^ Use the mask passwords plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can download below three plugins to mask the credentials in jenkins pipeline.

> Credentials plugin - provides a centralized way to define credentials that can be used by your Jenkins instance, plugins and build jobs.
>
> Credentials Binding plugin - allows you to configure your build jobs to inject credentials as environment variables.
>
> Plain Credentials plugin - a plugin dependency required by the Credentials Binding plugin.

For the detailed steps please refer this [blog](https://www.tikalk.com/posts/2017/03/07/how-to-mask-credentials-in-your-jenkins-jobs/) or [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs).

Comment: Hi @Yogesh Yadav Did you tried out mask passwords plugin or credential plugin? How did it go?